Why is Maven finding JUnit test cases without the Surefire plugin?
I'm trying to configure Maven to find and run my JUnit test cases, and I initially added the Surefire plugin for this purpose. However, I noticed that Maven is able to find and run the test cases even without explicitly including the Surefire plugin in my pom.xml.
I've read that Maven typically requires the Surefire plugin to detect and run JUnit tests, but now it seems to work without it.
Is this behavior due to a recent update in Maven, or is there another reason Maven is automatically finding and running the test cases?
Any clarification would be appreciated!

In the default life cycle, maven-surefire-plugin is bound to the approriate life cycle phase (https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) which means you don't need to add explicitly yourself... ... Also I bet in logging output you can see that maven-surefire-plugin has been run... and no that is not related to any update that's been the case since Maven 2...
